# Figure caption missing

Tags: floats, captions

I have this LaTeX document:

```
\section{header}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]

\KeywordTok{library}\NormalTok{(ggplot2)}
\KeywordTok{ggplot}\NormalTok{(mtcars, }\KeywordTok{aes}\NormalTok{(wt, hp)) +}\StringTok{ }\KeywordTok{geom_point}\NormalTok{()}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{figure}[H][htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{figure/model.png}
\caption{plot of chunk model}
\end{figure}
```

This produces this PDF:

[image: output]

There are 4 things that need fixing with PDF:

1. Get rid of `[]` above figure;
2. Get rid of `[H][htbp]` below figure;
3. Centre figure;
4. Show figure caption.

I've tried various combinations of LaTeX code without success. Doe anyone have solutions to above 4 tasks?

Comment: Which `\documentclass` are you using? Can you make your example complete? (I.e. include a minimal preamble and a `document` environment so that we can copy-paste the entire thing and compile it directly.)

Answer (score 3):

Meaningless part commented for clarity:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{header}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.

%\begin{Shaded}
%\begin{Highlighting}[]

%\KeywordTok{library}\NormalTok{(ggplot2)}
%\KeywordTok{ggplot}\NormalTok{(mtcars, }\KeywordTok{aes}\NormalTok{(wt, hp)) +}\StringTok{ }\KeywordTok{geom_point}\NormalTok{()}
%\end{Highlighting}
%\end{Shaded}

%\begin{figure}[H][htbp]
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
%\includegraphics{figure/model.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{it} % PS
\caption{plot of chunk model}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation:

1. `[H]` suggests that you want to use the package `here`, forcing the position of your picture. Then `[htbp]` is garbage. How we can see, your wishes 1, 2, and 3 are accomplished. Well, the first `[]` was from the commented `Highligting`.
2. Probably your image is too big. An optional parameter of `\includegraphics` scales here the picture to 0.8 of `\textwidth`. The value is to be chosen, of course. This should solve your 4th problem.

Comment: And do consider not using `[H]` as it leaves unnecessary gaps in the output. Learn to master `[htbp]` instead.